# Sample app for Phonegap/Cordova, React native, and iOS/Android native?

Tags: cordova, mobile, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

Does anyone know if there is a sample app built on those 4 platforms (Phonegap/Cordova, React Native, iOS and Android)? I want to be able to do a side-by-side comparison between the platforms built using the same 'app' that has the identical features/functionalities. Anyone know of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there are no identical apps in those 4 platforms.

What you can do is try some simple examples yourself and choose the best option to your needs.

If you are concerned about the future, performance and reliability, I recommend you to try React Native.

If you want something easy to work, specially for beginners, you might want to try with cordova, although React Native is pretty easy as well.

Native code (iOS and Android) take a lot more time to develop and provide the best performance. But only advanced developers can build apps in reasonable time.

If you are starting out, React Native or Cordova.

If you are good with Java / Obj-C or Swift, and have many developers and a big project, maybe you could go native.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to mark my answer as correct.